# Wordpress, Removing <ul> wrappers from dynamic_sidebar

Tags: wordpress

In Wordpress, when we call dynamic_sidebar('sidebar-id'); to our some template file, then this function generates ul wrappers arround the li items. Is there any way to remove that ul wrappers?

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
<div class="sidebar_class">
<?php if ( !function_exists('dynamic_sidebar') || !dynamic_sidebar('sidebar-id')) : ?>
<?php endif; ?>
</div>
```

Comment: But it stills adds ul wrappers around li items

Comment: This is the code which I place in some template file.                                                                                                                    <?php if ( !function_exists('dynamic_sidebar') || !dynamic_sidebar('sidebar-1') ) : ?>
<?php endif; ?>                                                                                                                    But it generates the ul wrappers arround li items. I don't want to use <div> tags as I don't need them

Comment: I'm pretty sure the sidebar works with generating <li> tags by default and you might end up with stranded <li> tags without the <ul> parent. However, you can define what comes before each widget with sidebar arguments in your functions.php file:

    register_sidebar( array(
        'name' => "Sidebar name",
        'id' => 'sidebar-id',
        'before_widget' => '<div id="yourID" class="widget-container">',
        'after_widget' => '</div>',
        'before_title' => '<h2 class="widget-title">',
        'after_title' => '</h2>',
    ) );

Comment: I am using the latest version of wordpress. There are not ul tags in my template file, the function itself wraps the li items by ul tag..I think due to latest version, it may include ul tags, may be previous versions don't include ul tags.

Comment: As I think its because of only the latest version which is now  Version 4.2.4, In older versions , I think this function don't wraps the li items by ul tags .You  can try this by installing the latest version of wordpress.

Answer (score 0):

In the Wordpress documentation you can see that its generating the `li` but not the `ul`, and you need to create it manually.

https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/dynamic_sidebar

Look at the general explanations here:
https://codex.wordpress.org/Sidebars

So it must be coming from your template system, if you can check.

Comment: But there is no ul tags in my template file, the function itself includes ul tags arround the li items...I am using the latest version of wordpress, may be that is the reason? You can try also by only using the function, it adds the ul tags arround the li items

Comment: Just to be sure - did you try in another browser? Some browser "auto complete" broken HTML.

I will try on my wordpress later and let you know.